# Updating RecyclerView data slows down the UI of the activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am working on a chat application and I am having some problems displaying the chat messages. For storage I'm using a Room database and in order to display the messages I'm using a RecyclerView. The problem is that the activity gets very slow and not so responsive on scrolling through messages.

Here is my code:

ChatActivity.java

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = ChatActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    public static Contact contact;
    public static boolean isContactConnected;

    private CircleImageView mContactPicture;
    private ImageView mContactConnected;
    private TextView mContactName;
    private TextView mContactStatus;

    private ChatAdapter mChatAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private EmojiconEditText mUserMessageInput;

    private View rootView;
    private ImageView emojiImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);

        initializeToolbar();

        String contactPhone = Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getStringExtra("phone"));
        contact = MainActivity.db.getContactDao().findByPhone(contactPhone);

        if (MainActivity.notificationMessages.get(contact.getId()) != null) {
            MainActivity.notificationMessages.put(contact.getId(), new ArrayList<Message>());
        }

        updateUI(contact);
        initializeViews();
        initializeRecyclerView();

        EmojIconActions emojIconActions = new EmojIconActions(this, rootView, mUserMessageInput, emojiImageView);
        emojIconActions.ShowEmojIcon();
        emojIconActions.setIconsIds(R.drawable.ic_baseline_keyboard_24, R.drawable.ic_baseline_emoji_emotions_24);

        mChatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Message>());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);

        MainActivity.db.getMessageDao().getLiveMessages(contactPhone).observe(this, new Observer<List<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Message> newMessages) {
                mChatAdapter.setMessages(newMessages);
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(newMessages.size() - 1);
            }
        });
    }

    [...]

    private void updateUI(Contact contact) {
        mContactName.setText(contact.getName());

        if (!contact.isConnected()) {
            Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);

            isContactConnected = false;
            mContactStatus.setText(
                    String.format(
                            "Last seen %s",
                            DateManager.getLastActiveText(
                                    df.format(currentTime),
                                    contact.getLastActive()
                            )
                    )
            );

            mContactConnected.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Log.d(TAG, "updateUI: initialized contact UI as disconnected");
        } else {
            mContactStatus.setText(R.string.active_now);
            mContactConnected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isContactConnected = true;

            Log.d(TAG, "updateUI: initialized contact UI as connected");
        }

        if (contact.getPhotoUri() != null) {
            Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(contact.getPhotoUri());

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                mContactPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                Log.d(TAG, "updateUI: loaded contact photo from device");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        ChatActivity.this,
                        "Failed to load image from device.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    [...]

    private void initializeRecyclerView() {
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chat_recycler_view);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager =
                new LinearLayoutManager(ChatActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        Log.d(TAG, "initializeRecyclerView: initialized RecyclerView");
    }

    [...]
}
```

AppDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {Contact.class, Message.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract ContactDao getContactDao();

    public abstract MessageDao getMessageDao();
}
```

MessageDao.java

```
@Dao
public interface MessageDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_from = :contact ORDER BY timestamp")
    List<Message> getMessages(String contact);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_from = :contact ORDER BY timestamp")
    LiveData<List<Message>> getLiveMessages(String contact);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_from =:contact AND status = 0")
    List<Message> getUndeliveredMessages(String contact);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE payloadId = :payloadId LIMIT 1")
    Message getMessageByPayloadId(long payloadId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_from = :contact ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
    Message getLastMessage(String contact);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_from = :contact ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
    LiveData<Message> getLastLiveMessage(String contact);

    @Query("DELETE FROM messages")
    void deleteAllMessages();

    @Insert
    void addMessage(Message message);

    @Update
    void updateMessage(Message message);

    @Delete
    void deleteMessage(Message message);
}
```

ChatAdapter.java

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Message> messages;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);

        int status = message.getStatus();

        if (status == Message.RECEIVED) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == 0) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.chat_message_item, parent, false);

            return new ChatUserViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.chat_message_item2, parent, false);

        return new ChatOtherViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message currentMessage = messages.get(position);

        String messageContent = currentMessage.getContent();
        Date date = currentMessage.getTimestamp();
        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.US);

        Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                ChatUserViewHolder mHolder = (ChatUserViewHolder) holder;

                Contact sender = MainActivity.db.getContactDao().findByPhone(currentMessage.getToFrom());

                if (sender.getPhotoUri() != null) {
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(sender.getPhotoUri());

                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        mHolder.getSenderProfilePicture().setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                mHolder.getSenderName().setText(sender.getName());
                mHolder.getMessageContent().setText(messageContent);
                mHolder.getTimestamp().setText(DateManager.getLastActiveText(ft.format(currentDate), ft.format(date)));
                break;

            case 1:
                ChatOtherViewHolder nHolder = (ChatOtherViewHolder) holder;

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("LOGIN_DETAILS", MODE_PRIVATE);

                String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "");
                String photoUri = sharedPreferences.getString("photoUri", null);

                if (photoUri != null) {
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(photoUri);

                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        nHolder.getSenderProfilePicture().setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                nHolder.getSenderName().setText(name);
                nHolder.getMessageContent().setText(messageContent);
                nHolder.getTimestamp().setText(DateManager.getLastActiveText(ft.format(currentDate), ft.format(date)));

                if (currentMessage.getStatus() == Message.SENT) {
                    nHolder.getMessageStatus().setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_done_24);
                } else {
                    nHolder.getMessageStatus().setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_done_all_24);
                }

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public void setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        if (this.messages.size() > 0) {
            this.messages.clear();
        }

        this.messages = messages;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

ChatItemViewHolder.java

```
class ChatItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CircleImageView mUserProfilePic;
    private ImageView mUserStatus;
    private TextView mUserProfileName;
    private EmojiconTextView mLastMessage;
    private TextView mTimestamp;

    public ChatItemViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mUserProfilePic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_image_item);
        mUserProfileName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name_item);
        mUserStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        mLastMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_status_item);
        mTimestamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
    }

    public CircleImageView getUserProfilePic() {
        return mUserProfilePic;
    }

    public ImageView getUserStatus() {
        return mUserStatus;
    }

    public TextView getUserProfileName() {
        return mUserProfileName;
    }

    public EmojiconTextView getLastMessage() {
        return mLastMessage;
    }

    public TextView getTimestamp() {
        return mTimestamp;
    }
}
```

ChatOtherViewHolder.java

```
class ChatOtherViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CircleImageView mSenderProfilePicture;
    private TextView mSenderName;
    private EmojiconTextView mMessageContent;
    private TextView mTimestamp;
    private ImageView mMessageStatus;

    public ChatOtherViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mSenderProfilePicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_profile_pic);
        mSenderName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_name);
        mMessageContent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_content);
        mTimestamp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_timestamp);
        mMessageStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_status);
    }

    public CircleImageView getSenderProfilePicture() {
        return mSenderProfilePicture;
    }

    public TextView getSenderName() {
        return mSenderName;
    }

    public EmojiconTextView getMessageContent() {
        return mMessageContent;
    }

    public TextView getTimestamp() {
        return mTimestamp;
    }

    public ImageView getMessageStatus() {
        return mMessageStatus;
    }
}
```

Clearly the problem comes from the RV. Initially I thought that the observe method running on the UI thread could be causing problems, but I replaced the action in the onChanged method and the UI is very smooth, so the problem occurs only when I try updating the RV items.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two big issues I see

1. Never do database calls in your adapter, database calls are too expensive to use in there.
2. You are also loading entire bitmaps into memory, use an image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load images, they handle recycled view and resizing the image to what they need to be along with asynchronous loading

Comment: Actually that did the trick! Thank you so much! I used Glide for image loading and I passed the contact data to the adapter on instantiation and now it works perfectly! Thank you :D